# Getting text from input form returns empty string, but console.log shows displays text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this is a commonly posted question so I apologize, but I've tried [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672155/how-to-get-text-from-input-tag), [jQUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088467/get-the-value-in-an-input-text-box), [parts of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906666/how-can-i-use-javascript-to-populate-a-div-with-input-from-an-input-text-box),several versions from previous work that DO work, .value, .textContent, .innerHTML, getAttribute('value'), document.getElementById and just everything else I could think of.

I console.log(user_name.value) and get the value I want, but when I console.log(name) or try to use user_name.value it's just an empty string. I'm new to development and got all the rest of the code working, everything else is hanging on this simple part and I can't solve it yet. Any help would be so appreciated.

HTML:

```
    <form>
        <input id="user_name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
        <input id="user_email" type="text" placeholder="Your E-mail" />
    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var name;
var email;

function reserveSeat(name, seatNumber, email) {

    var name = $('#user_name').getAttribute('value');

    var email = $('#user_email').getAttribute('value');

    var seatNumber = seatNumbers;

    reservedSeats.push (new CustomerReservation (name, seatNumber,   email));
    console.log(name)
    console.log(email)
};

$('.submitBtn').on('click', reserveSeat(name, seatNumber, email));
```

Answer (score 1):

You tried all but the right one:  `val()`

```
name = $('#user_name').val();

email = $('#user_email').val();
```

Note: if submitBtn is a type submit don't forget to prevent the default event,

```
$('.submitBtn').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    name = $('#user_name').val();
    email = $('#user_email').val();
    reservedSeats.push (new CustomerReservation (name, seatNumber,   email));
    console.log(name)
    console.log(email)

});
```

Note2: if your form is dynamically added don't forget to delegate your event

Comment: awesome. Thanks! this worked and helped me out so much!

Answer (score 0):

*there is no attribute called **value** in the input box and you are using jquery with javascript functions using **".val()"** is the right option*

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,

<form>
    <input id="user_name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input id="user_email" type="text" placeholder="Your E-mail" />
    <input id="submitBtn" type="submit" class="submitBtn"/>
</form>


$(document).on('click','.submitBtn',function(){

       var name = $('#user_name').val();
       var email = $('#user_email').val();

       console.log(name)
       console.log(email)

});
```

Comment: Thank you! New to dev and I knew the answer was out here and simpler than what I was trying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please review this one

```js
/*need gobal variable or not?? if not I will just remove it
var name;
var email; */


function reserveSeat(seatNumbers) {
  /*for savety*/
  seatNumber = Number(seatNumbers) || 5;
  /* change getAttribute(value) to val()*/
  var name = $('#user_name').val(),
    email = $('#user_email').val();

  reservedSeats.push(new CustomerReservation(name, seatNumber, email));
  console.log(name);
  console.log(email);
};

$('.submitBtn').on('click', reserveSeat(seatNumber));
```